# WEKA instances from SQL query data

Tags: instance, weka

I am wondering how to create the instance in WEKA without actually using CSV or ARRF file. i mean if ihave result of SQL query having four string fields, than how can i used that result to create instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using Weka Explorer and are coding this yourself, something like this should help you make an instance (in this code str1-str4 is your SQL result strings)! Note: This code requires you to load an .arff file with at least a couple of instances that are the same as what your new instances will be like!

```
Instance inst = new DenseInstance(4); 

inst.setValue(attr1, str1); 
inst.setValue(attr2, str2); 
inst.setValue(attr3, str3); 
inst.setValue(attr4, str4); 

inst.setDataset(instanceList); 

System.out.println("New instance: " + inst);
```

Comment: thanks, but i wish not to load arff file at all. i want to create instance  in memory from data received from sql.

Comment: What are you doing to the instance after it is created?

Comment: once instance is created than it will be used in kmean clustering algo for clustering the given data.

Comment: So you are going to cluster data using a model created using one instance?

Comment: no, offocourse not one instance, let me put it again, i wish to use all my data to bring in to instance object to train the model. i know i can use csv file to load the data in to instance, i am thinking not to use csv file and can take the data from sql directly

Comment: Try the above code without the line `inst.setDataset(instanceList);`. It could work for you.

Comment: thanks, but as you mentioned in your comments that this codes still requires to load the .arff file. what is the purpose of loading that .arff file.